# Adding elements of a list into a dictionary using .get() method

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of elements `[1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8]`. I want to put it into a dictionary so it would go `"key : how many times it appears in the list"`, so the dictionary looks something like as follows:

```py
{"1:1", "2:2", "5:2", "3:1", "7:1", "8:1"}
```

The solution should be applicable to any list.

I did the iteration of the list, but am receiving an error when it comes to adding the elements into the dictionary.

```
given = (1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8)
midwayDict = dict()
for element in given:
    midwayDict = midwayDict.get(element, 0)
print(midwayDict)
```

All it gives me is `" AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get' "`.
Is something wrong with the method I'm using? or should I use a different way?

I saw this being used somewhere a while ago, but I am not being able to find where of how exactly to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your code is

```
given = (1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8)
midwayDict = dict()
for element in given:
    midwayDict = midwayDict.get(element, 0)  # <- you are assigning 0 to dict so in next iteration you are accessing .get method on integer so its saying there is no get method on int object
print(midwayDict)
```

Should be

```
given = (1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8)
midwayDict = dict()
for element in given:
    _ = midwayDict.setdefault(element, 0)
    midwayDict[element] += 1
print(midwayDict)
```

Better is

```
from collections import Counter
given = (1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8)
print(Counter(given))
```

Comment: Thanks, now I remember that. Little mishap on me here. Counter won't work for me as I need more filtering after that

Comment: Counter is also a dictionary and you can do all stuff that you can do with regular dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one error in your code.

```py
given = (1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8)
midwayDict = dict()
for element in set(given):
    midwayDict[element] = midwayDict.get(element, 0)+1 # edited
print(midwayDict)
```

The better way to do this is by using dictionary comprehension.

```py
given = (1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5, 8)

d = {a:given.count(a) for a in set(given)}
print(d)
```

Comment: Thanks, now I remember that. Little mishap on me here

Comment: dictionary comprehension might be better, but I am afraid I am not yet on that level, and I prefer to only use structures I fully understand

Comment: @somepythonnoob You can take a look on this [link](https://www.codershubb.com/comprehensions-in-python/#:~:text=Comprehensions%20in%20python%201%20List%20comprehension.%20List%20comprehension,key%20and%20value%20pair.%204%20Generator%20comprehension.%20)

Comment: I would make it `for a in set(given)` to avoid unnecessary multiple counts of duplicate values

Comment: @Guillaume This is not necessary because the dictionary does not have duplicate keys even if you add them.

Comment: Sure, the resulting dictionary doesn't have duplicate keys. But the initial `given` list has duplicates elements, which will result in unnecessary iterations of the for loop. It will obviously not matter much for small input lists, but it may matter for huge lists with thousands / millions of entries.

Comment: @Guillaume Try this first `print({'a':12,'a':13})` this will print `{'a':13}`

Comment: That is not related to the issue I am trying to point at.